# Need some help with regular expressions (php)

Tags: php, regex

For example, I have the following code :

```
$string  = "adf  gggg  eere value aaaa bbb (10) value 
ddttt ggg www (20) value ddttt ggg www dddd (40) ";
preg_match("/(value).*(\(\d+\))/is", $string, $result);
var_dump($result[2]); // outputs 40.
```

I'm trying to get the first value (10). The code above outputs 40 which makes sense, but not what I want. The string pattern is : word "value", then a number of any characters, then "(", integer, ")". It seems that I'm missing something obvious... I haven't worked too much with regular expressions, but I believe it can be solved somehow with `?<!value`, no luck so far though.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`.*` is greedy, so it will match as many characters as possible, you want `.*?` which will match the minimum characters needed to complete the match:

```
/(value).*?(\(\d+\))/
```

Answer (score 2):

What's wrong with your regex is that .* is greedy, and tries to matchs as many letters as possible.

```
preg_match("#value.*?\((\d+)\)#is", $string, $result);
```

But you can make it faster by using a negative class:

```
preg_match("#value[^(]+\((\d+)\)#is", $string, $result);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
.*?value.*?\((\d+)\).*
```

Being *? a reluctant match.